# Advertise on Facebook can not get Google Play app data

Tags: android, facebook, google-play, ads, mobile-application

When I try to advertise my Google Play App on Facebook, app data is not reachable by Facebook. If I try another random app from Google Play, it works perfect (app icon, app name and an image automatically filled, ad preview looks complete).

It looks like Facebook cached my app data and I can not refresh. Please see attached images.

Right now I can not advertise my application on Facebook. Is there anyone had similar problem who can help me about this case.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried a name change on my application on Google play and after couple of days, facebook managed to fetch my application through the google play link. Looks like a cashing situation.